# Multiple threads RxJava with .subscribe vs .concatmap

Tags: java, callback, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm attempting to send an array of requests to an endpoint with `Observable.fromIterable(array).subscribe()` with the intent for each item to hit the backend in sequence.

Currently, the Observable is not waiting for the async task of posting to the endpoint to complete before firing off the next request. I have two potential ideas but not sure how to implement either.

1. Move `.subscribe().onNext()` to the callback to ensure each element is called after the async task is completed.
2. Use `.concatmap` instead. I've seen this posted as a recommended method for people with similar actions as myself, some array of items with async tasks, but I'm not sure why it would work or how it works differently than what I have above.

Comment: It sounds like you are using Retrofit (or some similar network mechanism) that returns an Observable per request. If so, the calls are not fired until the `subscribe` block. Therefore, to meet the requirement of waiting for each call, you need to explicitly wait for each call to finish. You can either do a `blockingGet` instead a `map` or implement synchronous requests from the API. Then you perform the synchronous request inside a background thread of your RxJava chain. I can fill out a better answer if you provide more context to your question.

Comment: Both of your proposed solutions will not work because they do not address the root issue, which is that the network calls are not executed until subscribe.
Solution 1 suggests `onNext()`, but this doesn't stop the chain, it only adds a hook for events passing through. Solution 2 suggests `concatMap`, but again, this doesn't fix the fact that the items emitted hit subscribe at nearly the same time (they don't wait for the network to complete).

Answer (score 0):

The `fromIterable()` operator emits every item that it can. Downstream has to manage waiting on asynchronous operations using one of the `map()` operators.

```
Observable.fromIterable(array)
  .flatMap( item -> 
             Observable.fromCallable( asyncOp( item ) ), // 1
             1) // 2
  .subscribe(); // 3
```

1. The `fromCallable()` makes the asynchronous operation into an observable.
2. The number `1` is the "maximum parallelism" imposed by `flatMap`. That means that `flatMap()` will only subscribe to one subject and wait for the result before processing the next one.
3. Your `subscribe()` operator should always have an `onError()` handler in it. Otherwise, upstream errors may crash the thread.